# how to view OOM killer logs in Mac OS?

Tags: c, macos

If the swap partition is  not enabled, run the following code, the process will be killed by the operating system, which may be caused by insufficient memory. I want to check the specific log on the Mac computer, can anyone help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MEM_SIZE 1024 * 1024 * 1024

int main() {
    char* addr[4];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        addr[i] = (char*) malloc(MEM_SIZE);
        if(!addr[i]) {
        
            return -1;
        }
        
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
       
        memset(addr[i], 0, MEM_SIZE);
    }
    
   
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior since `64 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` leads to integer overflow. `long` and `int` are likely both 32 bits large so neither will work. This is why your program gets killed. As for how to check some log on Mac, I have no idea.

Comment: I modified the question and code

Comment: OOM Killer is a Linux phenomenon.  There isn't an OOM Killer on macOS.

Comment: Related: [How does OSX handle Out of Memory conditions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257593/3000)